# Can (or could) one suppress macro replacement in C by enclosing the name in brackets

Tags: c, macros

I seem to recall that one could suppress replacement (expansion) of a macro in C by placing the macro name in brackets, e.g. `(free)(p)` would call the function `free` whether or not a macro `free` were defined. I see no mention of this in the C99 standard (*it is there, see answer)*, and I observe that <del>MSVS 2013 does not implement it either</del>. *Added in light of answer: It does, just as the standard requires, i.e. only for **function-like** macros, whose expansion is **triggered by a following ‘`(`’** and thus inhibited by the intervening ‘`)`’.*

Am I dreaming, or was there such a possibility, and if so, what was the rationale for withdrawing it? Or was present only in certain dialects?

Comment: It is an old dog's trick (pre C99), MSVS should handle it flawlessly. Can you provide an example with your observation?

Comment: The relevant mention in the standard is section 6.10.3, paragraph 10, from which I excerpt (emphasis added): "Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name **followed by a ( as the next preprocessing token** introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition (an invocation of the macro)."

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Thanks, but no longer needed: the answer from FUZxxl and the comment from rici solve my problem. I had forgotten (or never known) that it only applies to **function-like macros** and not checked the standard carefully enough:(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A function-like macro `FOO`

```
#define FOO(x) ...
```

is only expanded when the token `FOO` appears followed by a `(` token. Thus, to prevent the expansion of `FOO`, `(FOO)` can be used. Just as you said. This however only applies to function-like macros.

This is specified in ISO 9899:2011 §6.10.3 ¶10, which reads:

> 10 A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> > **# define** *identifier lparen identifier-list<sub>opt</sub>* **)** *replacement-list new-line*
> >     **# define** *identifier lparen* **... )** *replacement-list new-line*
> >     **# define** *identifier lparen identifier-list* **, ... )** *replacement-list new-line*
>
> defines a *function-like macro* with parameters, whose use is
>   similar syntactically to a function call. The parameters are specified
>   by the optional list of identifiers, whose scope extends from their
>   declaration in the identifier list until the new-line character that
>   terminates the **#define** preprocessing directive. Each subsequent
>   instance of the function-like macro name followed by a **(** as the next
>   preprocessing token introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens
>   that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition (an
>   invocation of the macro). The replaced sequence of preprocessing
>   tokens is terminated by the matching **)** preprocessing token, skipping
>   intervening matched pairs of left and right parenthesis preprocessing
>   tokens. Within the sequence of preprocessing tokens making up an
>   invocation of a function-like macro, new-line is considered a normal
>   white-space character.